# set attribute 'selected' to selected options on select list multiple

Tags: javascript

I have a list established as multiple, I want that when selecting one or more options to be able to establish the 'selected' attribute to each of the selected options, if any of them is deselected remove the 'selected' attribute from that option, this can be done alone with pure javascript?

```js
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');

    for (const select of selects) {
        const options = select.options,
            selected_options = select.selectedOptions,
            multiple = select.hasAttribute('multiple');
        select.addEventListener('change', function(ele) {
            if (multiple) {
                // Here should be the event for the multiple list, I can't do it.
            } else {
                for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    const option = options[i];
                    Array.prototype.filter.call(option.parentNode.children, function () {
                        if(option.selected) {
                            option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected')
                        } else {
                            option.removeAttribute('selected')
                        }
                    })
                }                   
            }
        })
    }
```

```html
<select name="second" class="form-select" aria-label="Second select example" id="selectSecond">
    <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
    <option value="a">One A</option>
    <option value="b">Two B</option>
    <option value="c">Three C</option>
</select>

<select name="third[]" class="form-select" aria-label="Third select example" id="selectThird" multiple>
    <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
    <option value="a1">A One</option>
    <option value="a2">A Two</option>
    <option value="a3">A Three</option>
    <option value="a4">A Four</option>
    <option value="a5">A Five</option>
    <option value="a6">A Six</option>
</select>
```

I hope I have explained myself well and you can help me. Thanks in advance. Kind regards.

Comment: This sounds like a weird requirement, can you explain why you want this to happen?

Comment: I want that when clicking on any option of the multiple list the attribute is set, but it does not interfere with the simple list, each type of list separately. I explain?

Comment: No, look. I want to know *why* you want to add/remove the `selected` attribute to the <option> elements. Forget the first <select> for a second. What is your goal here? Why do you care whether the options have a `selected` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I test it work fine , can you respond to any problems encountered?

```js
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');

for (const select of selects) {
  const options = select.options,
        selected_options = select.selectedOptions,
        multiple = select.hasAttribute('multiple');
  select.addEventListener('change', function(ele) {
    if (multiple) {
      for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        const option = options[i];
        if(option.selected) {
          option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected')
        } else {
          option.removeAttribute('selected')
        }
        console.log(option.text,option.getAttribute('selected'));
      }
    } else {
      for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        const option = options[i];
        Array.prototype.filter.call(option.parentNode.children, function () {
          if(option.selected) {
            option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected')
          } else {
            option.removeAttribute('selected')
          }
        })
      }                   
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<select name="second" class="form-select" aria-label="Second select example" id="selectSecond">
    <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
    <option value="a">One A</option>
    <option value="b">Two B</option>
    <option value="c">Three C</option>
</select>

<select name="third[]" class="form-select" aria-label="Third select example" id="selectThird" multiple>
    <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
    <option value="a1">A One</option>
    <option value="a2">A Two</option>
    <option value="a3">A Three</option>
    <option value="a4">A Four</option>
    <option value="a5">A Five</option>
    <option value="a6">A Six</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks that way it works correctly, in the end it was easy but I didn't see it.